# Why must we supply a port number in addition to an IP when sending a request?

Tags: networking, ip, port-forwarding, ports

I have a decent understanding of the practical use of ports and how they work. However, I have a few questions I would like to clear up.

1. What happens if we send a request without specifying a port for the server socket?
2. Is there a way to setup a machine so that instead of having a process listen on a particular port, I have all requests sent to my IP address be handled by the same process? In which case, the client could omit the port in the request.
3. Building off of question 2, if I just want to run a server of some sort on something like a Raspberry Pi, could I have it so that my IP address routes to my RPi, which handles any and all incoming network requests using the same server?
   Which is to say, people just connect to the IP address, sans port number, to connect to my server.

Comment: I'm just going to comment instead of writing an answer to each element that has been explained to some degree in the existing answers.  WHAT IS MISSING from those answers is the function of your router.  Settign up port forwarding in your router allows you to send port XX to Server A, while port YY can point to your rPi, and port ZZ can point to some other machine.

Answer (score 3):

> Why must we supply a port number in addition to an IP when sending a request?

Because the TCP (and UDP) protocol requires it. It is part of the protocol specification.

> What happens if we send a request without specifying a port for the server socket?

Well, if you don't specify a port number there will presumably be zeroes in that part of the API call. Port 0 is a reserved port and some implementations use it to mean a port is dynamically allocated by the system.

> Is there a way to setup a machine so that instead of having a process listen on a particular port, I have all requests sent to my IP address be handled by the same process?

Not if you use TCP or UDP transport-layer protocols or any of the application-level protocols built on them. Such as HTTP

In some operating systems there is a single process as part of the OS, but it hands off connections to specific applications.

> could I have it so that my IP address routes to my RPi

You could configure the router to route all incoming connection requests to your rPi

> people just connect to the IP address, sans port number, to connect to my server.

Not using standard protocols such as HTTP.

I think it's not possible using standard APIs such as Berkely Sockets. I imagine you could, with some effort, use a different, or new, transport layer protocol of your own devizing. You'd need some pretty solid reasons to go to all that inconvenience.

Comment: With regard to block 4, what happens, on both the client and server, if some arbitrary port gets forwarded to my RPi and I'm not listening for that port? Likewise, would it be feasible to have all incoming requests be handled by the same server? (assuming all connections are already being routed to the RPi). That is to say, I imagine one could create as many sockets as there are available ports and listen on all of them. However, is there some sort of "listen all" function that would enable a server process to receive all requests made to any port?

Comment: @Wolfram: A) Such packets would be discarded. B) None that I know of. C) If you want a discussion, this Q&A site may be the wrong place. You could try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

> What happens if we send a request without specifying a port for the server socket?

You can't, a socket is an IP + port by definition.  The reason why ports exist is because multiple programs on a machine can be sending/receiving traffic and the ports are used to differentiate between processes on either end.

> Is there a way to setup a machine so that instead of having a process listen on a particular port, I have all requests sent to my IP address be handled by the same process?

You could have your process open 65535 sockets, one on each port.  You can't make an existing program do this that isn't written to do that without some sort of weird intermediary program that you'd probably have to write yourself.

On Linux, you might be able to create an `iptables` configuration that does this, or something equivalent.

> if I just want to run a server of some sort on something like a Raspberry Pi, could I have it so that my IP address routes to my RPi, which handles any and all incoming network requests using the same server?

The default situation on most standard residential routers is for your router to ignore any traffic someone from the outside sends it.

On almost all such routers you can do port forwarding, which tells your router to forward incoming traffic on a specific port to a specific system on your private network behind the router.

You can probably also tell your router to forward any unsolicited incoming traffic to a specific IP on your private network behind the router.  This is called a DMZ.

Answer (score 1):

Ports are essential for protocols that allow multiple process to communicate between servers.  This is more than a practical consideration.

Well Known Services have assigned ports: DNS=53, HTTP=80, HTTPS=443, SMTP=25, Telnet=23, SSH=22, FTP=20&21, etc.  For such well known services, it is not necessary to specify the port if they are running on the port assigned to the service. The assigned ports are listed in /etc/services on Unix/Linux platforms.

1. For TCP and UDP, you can't make connections without a port.  The header includes fields for both source and destination ports.  There will always be a value in these fields, even if it is zero.
2. It is possible to capture all packets arriving on an interface.  This is how tools like tcpdump work.
3. As noted in 1, all incoming requests will have a port number.  SOHO routers usually support a DMZ and will forward all incoming requests not otherwise routed, to the IP address assigned to the DMZ.  In most cases, you just need to forward the port(s) required for the service to the server (your Raspberry Pi).  This would allow you to have multiple Raspberry Pis running different services.

Comment: With regard to the last sentence, I imagine this also enables for multiple servers to be run on the same machine, so long as they are listening on different ports?

Comment: @Wolfram Yes, you can run different servers processes for different (or the same) services on different ports.  As long as you have sufficient resources (cpu, memory, storage, etc.), they can run on the same Raspberry Pi.